# How can I apply this validation function to all inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, file, input

I have this code that works to validate just one input file, but I need to validate multiple fields (since the users can add as much "input files" as they want) and don't now how. I've being trying to use loops but with no results (mostly because I don't understand them even when I've been reading it over and over in w3school).

https://jsfiddle.net/ElenaMcDowell/2xrqp6zg/2/

```
$( ".postreplyForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
var fileBox = $('.post-file').val(); //This is the Class of the input file
if (fileBox === '') {
   //If there is no file
   return;
} else {
   //File format
   var fileExtension = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'pdf', 'pps', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'xls', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt'];
   if ($.inArray($('.post-file').val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
      $(".errorFile").html('<br><center><p class="signuperror">File format not allowed.</p></center><br>');
   } else {
      $(".errorFile").html(' ');
      //File size
      var fileSize = $('.post-file')[0].files[0].size;
      if (fileSize > 1000000) {
         $(".errorFile").html('<br><center><p class="signuperror">The file is too big.</p></center><br>');
      } else {
         $(".errorFile").html(' ');
         return;
      }

   }

}
});
```

Comment: If there can be multiple `.post-file` then you need to loop over it, and treat each one individually.  `$('.post-file').each((index, file) => { ...do stuff... });`

Comment: I tried with each(), but then validates one that is correct and submits the form before validating the one the other one (that I purposely upload heavier or with the wrong format to see it the validation works). :(

Comment: Outside of the loop, `var valid = true;`  If at any point you hit an error, `valid = false`.  And after you are done with the loop, `if (!valid) event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Sorry, but still does not work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all values using `$('.post-file')[0].files` then loop through each files and check condition then print some message in your div `errorFiles` . Also , use some variable and set  it to `true` and if any condition doesn't meet set to `false` depending on this variable prevent your form to submit.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".postreplyForm").submit(function(event) {
  var fileBox = $('.post-file').val();
  if (fileBox === '') {
    return false; //prevent form to submit
  } else {
    //File format
    var fileExtension = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'mp3', 'mp4', 'pdf', 'pps', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'xls', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt'];
    var flag = true; //decalre this
    var fileArray = $('.post-file')[0].files; //get all files
    $(".errorFile").html('');
    //loop through files
    $.each(fileArray, function(i, v) {
      name = v.name; //name of file
      fileSize = v.size; //size of file
      console.log(name);
      if ($.inArray(name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase(), fileExtension) == -1) {
        flag = false;
        $(".errorFile").html('<br><center><p class="signuperror">File format not allowed.</p></center><br>');
      } else {
        if (fileSize > 1000000) {
          $(".errorFile").html('<br><center><p class="signuperror">The file is too big.</p></center><br>');
          flag = false;
        }
      }
    })
  }
  //check not true prevnt submit
  if (!flag) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

});
```

```css
.errorFile {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="create-mode postreplyForm" method="post" action="a.php" name="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table class="table-newpost">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5"><br>
        <div style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: -10px;">Attach file</div>
        <br>
        <span>File formats allowed: (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .mp3, .mp4, .pdf, .zip, .rar, .pps, .ppt, .pptx, .xls, .doc, .docx, .txt, .rtf)</span>
        <br><br>
        <div class="fileBox">
          <div style="display: flex; margin-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="fileID1" class="post-file" multiple="multiple">
            <div id="1" class="fileBtn fileDeleteInPost" title="Delete file">x</div>
            <div class="fileBtn add-file" title="Add file">+</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="errorFile"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right;">
        <input type="hidden" name="reply-by" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userId']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="submit-postreply" id="Miau">Submit</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still just check the first file and not the others. I don't get why, but if the first input returns true, it submits the form no matter than the second file is too big and should return false.

Comment: did you tried running above code ? does above code also show same behaviour ?

Comment: Yes, I did run the above code and it does have the same behaviour. :(